# How can we pass a reference from Node into a Puppeteer page?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Is there any way to pass a reference to a page in Puppeteer? Or is it limited only to serializable data?

For example, I'm imagining doing `page.exposeFunction('require', ...)` to begin making my own Electron, but that won't work if we can only return serializable data.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. `exposeFunction` defines a function that will be executed in the Node.JS context; are you asking about returning the value of that function to the browser?

Comment: @Aankhen f.e. I want to return a function instance, or instance of some other class, without serializing.

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer provides an API to control Chromium over the DevTools Protocol, which means that the [Page class](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page) utilizes the [Page Domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page) from the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

The return values obtained from the Page domain are all serializable.

Therefore, it appears that you are limited only to serializable data.

Comment: It'd be nice not to have to serialize. Is there a way?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Things from different contexts (Node.JS vs. browser) have to be serialized, as the answer states.